# Reading timestamps from a txt.file and plotting them on X- axis with matplotlib (Web-server)

Tags: python, matplotlib, web, plot, web-applications

I have created a web application with Python and Pyramid that fetches the latest email from gmail, saves the data to a file and then plots the data with matplotlib and converts it into a html string with mpld3. I currently have the data in following form in my emails:

```
17  25

18  25

19  25

20  26
```

I have no issues plotting this data. However, I would like to plot the data in the same form, but with timestamps, like this:

```
25-06-2018 9:11  25

25-06-2018 9:12  25

25-06-2018 9:13  25

...
```

I've tried converting the data to datetime format, but with no success. Here is my code:

```
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from pyramid.response import Response
import email
import getpass
import imaplib
import os
import re
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, mpld3

def imaptest(request):

    m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
    m.login('email@gmail.com', 'password')
    m.list()
    m.select('inbox')

    result, data = m.uid('search', None, 'UNSEEN')

    i = len(data[0].split()) #space separate string

    for x in range(i):
        latest_email_uid = data[0].split()[x]
        result, email_data = m.uid('fetch', latest_email_uid, '(RFC822)')
        raw_email = email_data[0][1]
        raw_email_string = raw_email.decode('utf-8')
        email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email_string)


        for part in email_message.walk():
            if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
                body = part.get_payload(decode=True)
                save_string = str('C:\Email\mail1' + str(x) + '.txt')
                myfile = open(save_string, 'a')
                myfile.write(str(body))
                myfile.close
            else:
                continue

        with open('C:\Email\mail10.txt') as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            x = [int(line.split()[0]) for line in lines]
            y = [int(line.split()[1]) for line in lines]

            fig = plt.figure()
            ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
            ax1.set_title('Test Graph')
            ax1.set_xlabel('Time')
            ax1.set_ylabel('Temperature')

            plt.plot(x,y)


    # Print as HTML
            return Response(   
            mpld3.show()
            )

config = Configurator()
config.add_route('imaptest', '/imaptest')
config.add_route('landingpage', '/landingpage')
config.add_view(landingpage, route_name='landingpage')
config.add_view(imaptest, route_name='imaptest')
app = config.make_wsgi_app()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while I figured it out.

Firstly, I have to convert my time values into string arrays and not int arrays:

```
lines = f.readlines()
dates = [str(line.split()[0]) for line in lines]
```

Then I convert the array to a datetime type array with datetime module:

```
from datetime import datetime
date = [datetime.strptime(x,'%d-%m-%Y/%H:%M') for x in dates]
```

Then I just plot the datetime on X- axis and my values on Y- axis with matplotlib:

```
plt.subplot(2,1,1)      
plt.title('Temperature & Humidity')
plt.ylabel('Temperature' + u'\u2103')
plt.plot_date(date, y, 'r.-')
```

Here is the whole code, just in case someone else could have use of it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, mpld3
from datetime import datetime



def landingpage(request):

    with open('C:\Email\mail10.txt') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        dates = [str(line.split()[0]) for line in lines]
        y = [float(line.split()[1]) for line in lines]
        z = [float(line.split()[2]) for line in lines]

        date = [datetime.strptime(x,'%d-%m-%Y/%H:%M') for x in dates]

        plt.subplot(2,1,1)

        plt.title('Temperature & Humidity')
        plt.ylabel('Temperature' + u'\u2103')
        plt.plot_date(date, y, 'r.-')


        plt.subplot(2,1,2)
        plt.plot_date(date, z, 'b.-')
        plt.xlabel('Time')
        plt.ylabel('Humidity RH%'.decode('unicode-escape'))






    # Print as HTML
        return Response(   
        mpld3.show()
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need date and time both then https://stackoverflow.com/a/51037906/10739643 answer is best.
What if someone need only the date then you have to just add this :

```
date = [datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(str(y[0]),'%Y-%m-%d'),'%Y-%m-%d') for x in dates]
```

Full formation will be:

```
 import from datetime import datetime
 with open('file.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    dates = [str(line.split()[0]) for line in lines]


date = [datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(str(y[0]),'%Y-%m-%d'),'%Y-%m-%d') for x in dates]
```